# Kafka Stream - How to use the Suppress function?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

As I implemented my business rule for my project, I need to reduce the number of events produced by the stream application to save the resource and to make the processor as fast as possible.
I figured out that Kafka offers the ability to suppress intermediate events base on either their RecordTime or WindowEndTime. My code with the usage of suppress:

```
KTable<Long, ProductWithMatchRecord> productWithCompetitorMatchKTable = competitorProductMatchWithLinkInfo.groupBy(
        (linkMatchProductRecordId, linkMatchWithProduct) -> KeyValue.pair(linkMatchWithProduct.linkMatch().tikiProductId(), linkMatchWithProduct),
        Grouped.with(longPayloadJsonSerde, linkMatchWithProductJSONSerde).withName("group-match-record-by-product-id")
).aggregate(
        ProductWithMatchRecord::new,
        (tikiProductId, linkMatchWithProduct, aggregate) -> aggregate.addLinkMatch(linkMatchWithProduct),
        (tikiProductId, linkMatchWithProduct, aggregate) -> aggregate.removeLinkMatch(linkMatchWithProduct),
        Named.as("aggregate-match-record-by-product-id"),
        Materialized
                .<Long, ProductWithMatchRecord, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("match-record-by-product-id")
                .withKeySerde(longPayloadJsonSerde)
                .withValueSerde(productWithMatchRecordJSONSerde)
)
.suppress(Suppressed.untilTimeLimit(Duration.ofSeconds(10), null));
```

Basically, it is just a KTable that take the input from other KTable, aggregation, join,....
and then **Suppress**

The problem is I expect for 1 event of 1 given key, if there is no event for this key in the next 10 seconds, the corresponding data in **productWithCompetitorMatchKTable** will be produced.
However, after 10 seconds (or more), no event of the given is fired, until I made another event for this key.
Please help me to fix the problem or refer to some source of documentation that I can understand more about the suppress feature of Kafka stream application.

I have tried to debug and the code and change many configurations of the Suppressed.untilTimeLimit function, however, it wwas not working as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need new events, to trigger the "time check".
Have a look at "punctuate".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).